# Android SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase returns the path instead of the Database itself

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to open a database passed from a intent,
when I try to open the DB it will return the DB path instead of the DB self, so when I try to perform SQLite commands it wont work

```
URI uri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
SQLiteDatabase oldDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(uri.getPath(), null, 1);
database.selectTable(oldDB)

//select table from old DB
selectTable(SQLiteDatabase oldDB){
       database.execSQL("SELECT * FROM " +
                       oldDB +
                       ".table1"
}
```

will result in error:
SELECT * FROM SQLiteDatabase: /mnt/sdcard/path/to/database.db.table1
I need to get the actual Database "SELECT * FROM nameOfDatabase.table1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to open the DB it will return the DB path instead of the DB self

No, it does not. `toString()` on a `SQLiteDatabase` returns the path. You are concatenating `toString()` on a `SQLiteDatabase` in your query, for unknown reasons. If you want to perform a query on `oldDB`, call `query()` or `rawQuery()` on `oldDB`, not whatever `database` is.

Comment: `database` is just an instance of [SQLiteDatabase ](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), using `rawQuery` didnt help either, I set up to catch ExseptionError, and retuns a log: E/Error﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: ":" (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT * FROM SQLiteDatabase: /mnt/sdcard/path/to/database.db.table1

Comment: @EH: That is because `CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT * FROM SQLiteDatabase: /mnt/sdcard/path/to/database.db.table1` is not a valid SQL statement. "I need to get the actual Database "SELECT * FROM nameOfDatabase.table1" -- as CL notes, since you have not run an `ATTACH` statement, and so `nameOfDatabase.table1` is *also* invalid. If you want to use `oldDB`, then **use `oldDB` directly**, and get rid of `database`.

Comment: the question is how can I get the hang of that Database Object?

Comment: like you said I had to first `ATTACH` the oldDb then just use `uri.getPath()` to get the path, working fine

Answer (score 1):

The name of a database that you have opened with `openDatabase` is always `main`.

You get different database names only when you actually attach a database to another, i.e., when you execute an [ATTACH statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) on a database.